# Is there any utility like smartctl which gives identify data for an ATAPI device?

Tags: 14.04, boot, hard-drive, disk-utility

I want to know the `identify data` for the `ATAPI device(CD/DVD ROM)` I am using.

I can get the same information using the `smartctl --identify /dev/device` for the `ATA Hard Disk` but the same is not available for the CD/DVD Drives.

Is there any other command/utility which can give me such information. I am looking for an output in the same format as `smartctl --identify` gives.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hdparm --identify` ( or -I ) /dev/device reads and interprets the ATA device IDENTIFY DEVICE data.

Comment: Hdparm --Istdout /dev/device writes the Identify data to stdout as an array of hexs.